# Execute javascript code from android service when app is closed

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, hybrid

I want to execute a javascript function from native android even when the application was closed.

I have a service in android and i called the javascript function every hour or minutes like this:

```
private class mainTask extends TimerTask
{ 
    public void run() 
    {
       fireEvent("event", null);  
       //this calls webView.sendJavascript(js);
    }
}
```

This is working well while the application is still in the foreground, it calls the javascript function in the hybrid part,

but when I closed/kill the app the service is still running and the fireEvent function and webView.sendJavascript(js) were still executed but the javascript function is not executed anymore.

This is my js:

```
cordova.plugins.background.event = function () {
    console.log("background mode on active");
    //also put a javascript notification here to know if its executed.
}
```

Am I missing something or its not possible to execute a javascript code if the application is close?

Comment: when app is background, js code can't execute. Only run native code.

Comment: can you show some documentation or support to your answer?                In here https://github.com/christocracy/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation it says that a callback can be called and its running in background, I'm just not totally sure if it calls the callback if the app was killed since i haven't tested it.

Comment: plugin-background-geolocation use native code to post tracking location to your server when app in background. In document, plugin's author said: in IOS, callback js can trigger after app in background and Android then callback js will not fire, all js will be stop in Android.

Answer (score 0):

if the app is closed... you can't execute code of this app.

You could: 
 1. execute code outside of the app... (but this is maybe not what you want)
 2. try to launch again silently the app (not sure exactly if you can do that from a service)